# Python Selenium's Key.RETURN is not returing new web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("python")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This code suppose to send "python" in the web page's search box and fetch a new web page but its not working and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put some delay/wait before passing return key.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("python")
time.sleep(2)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: I worked perfectly but can you give me the reason behind it so that  I can improve my programming.

Comment: Basically the element was not rendered properly, and we had to use wait to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick can be, when you enter text in the text box, try to simulate user action. for example, in this case, click on that text box and then enter.(refer to the code comment).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("python")
elem.click() # add this line to your code
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```